# Different background for each actionbar tab

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

In my app I've got three tabs in an actionbar (using ActionBarSherlock). In an xml
style I set/overwrite default background selector and everything works well. But... now I've got to set individual backgrounds for each tab. Visually I want to have my tabs with different underline color.

Ideally I'd like to have something like this:

```
Tab t = actionBar.newTab();
t.setBackground(...);
actionBar.addTab(t);
```

But there is no method setBackground.

So, I created a custom view for the tabs and now I have this:

[image]

The first problem is the size. I'd like to have exactly the same size I had with standard/default tabs.
The second problem is the background selector doesn't work. When I press a not selected tab it doesn't change its state/background, and it is the same selector that works perfectly with TabView.background.

What I'd like to have exactly is standard actionbar tabs with different background selector for each tab. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, How did you solve your problems? Please share.